# viewDidLoad in UITextView subclass?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, cocoa

Cocoa/Objective-C noob here.

I'm working on a simple app to learn some more about iOS development, and am struggling to see how my subclass of `UITextView` has it's `viewDidLoad` method called.

I am subclassing `UITextView` to `CMTextView`.

Using storyboard, I have a `CMTextView` in the window.

In `CMTextView.m`, I have the following:

```
#import "CMTextView.h"

@interface UITextView ()

- (id)styleString;

@end

@implementation CMTextView

- (id)styleString {
    return [[super styleString] stringByAppendingString:@"; line-height: 1.1em"];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    NSLog(@"LOADED!"); // not doing anything...
}
```

I'm not doing anything fancy to add this as a subview of my window, but I thought the storyboard did that for me?

Does anyone have any advice?

Comment: you are confusing between UIView subclasses and UIViewController subclasses

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The above answers are correct if you manually initialize the `UITextView`. If loading them from a nib, you need to override the `-awakeFromNib` method.

```
-(void)awakeFromNib
{
    [super awakeFromNib]; // Don't forget to call super

    //Do more intitialization here
}
```

If you want to handle the resizing also override the `-layoutSubviews` method

Answer (score 5):

`viewDidLoad` is a method in `UIViewController` not `UIView`/`UITextView`

if you want to do any initialize then put it in `initWithFrame:`

Answer (score 2):

`viewDidLoad` is a `UIViewController` method (see [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewDidLoad)).

`UIKit` ensures that `viewDidLoad` is called at appropriate times when you instantiate a view controller's view, but it has no role to play in a `UIView` like `UITextView`.

Usually, you prepare your view at `initWithFrame` time.

Answer (score 1):

A view can never have the method viewDidLoad.
Some methods are tethered only to the viewcontroller and `viewDidLoad` is one of them.

The method constructors for views would be

```
-(id)init;
-(id)initWithFrame;
```